# Deny permission to camera on browser

Tags: playwright

I need to write an automated test for an application that uses the device's camera from the browser. For that I'll need to deny the permission to the camera and upload an image, otherwise the browser displays the prompt asking for camera access and that blocks the automated test. On Playwright's documentation, I have only seen the grantPermissions and clearPermissions methods. Is it currently possible to deny access to the camera so I can automate this test case with Playwright? I haven't found anything on the web, on Stack Overflow or on SQA Stack Exchange.

Comment: I'm not quite sure but could you try calling `grantPermissions` passing an empty array?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Don't look for anything difficult in it. If you don't grant permissions, then they are denied.

If you want to be explicit to make for example it easier for other people to understand your intent, you can use an empty array.

An example when creating a new context could be:

```js
context = await browser.newContext({
    ...options.contextConfig(),
    permissions: [],
});
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I get a `ReferenceError: options is not defined` with `...options.contextConfig(),`. I don't see that method in the documentation. Do you know where can I find it there?

Comment: Instantiating the Context with only an empty `permissions` argument, without the `...options.contextConfig()`, worked.

Comment: @Marco.S: you won't find that in documentation, it's taken from my file, it's something I use, the point was the empty permission array.